# MYSQL/PHP JOIN and exclude condition

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have tables tags and items and a third table tagitem that matches tags to items. Users can go to the item page which gets populated with a list of tags.  Upon clicking on the tag, a row is inserted in the tagitem table, tagging the item.

To prevent users from applying the same tag to an item twice, I'd like the list of tags that comes up to exclude any already applied to the item.  So I think the query that pulls the tags should have a condition in it that excludes tags already assigned to a given item.   However, I am having trouble doing this.

Tables are:

tags

```
id|tag
```

items

```
id|item
```

tagitem

```
id|tagid|itemid
```

A query that pulls all the tags would just be:

```
"SELECT * FROM tags"
```

Since the table with the info on tags matched to items is tagitem, I have joined them.  I need to figure out how to include a condition roughly described in parentheses below that excludes any tag that has an entry in the tagitem table for the item in question.

```
SELECT t.*,ti.*
FROM `tags` t
LEFT JOIN `tagitem` ti
on t.id = ti.tagid
WHERE
ti.tagid NOT IN (SELECT * FROM tagitem WHERE itemid = '22')
GROUP BY t.id
```

This is as far as I've gotten.  (Right now I'm getting some wierd operand error.)  Would appreciate any suggestions on proper way to do this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is by altering the table and adding *CONSTRAINT* on the table to have unique tag per item,

```
ALTER TABLE tagitem ADD UNIQUE ti_idx (tagid,itemid)
```

But if you only what do it in your query, try this one below

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tags a
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT tagid 
            FROM tagitem 
            WHERE itemid = '22'
        ) b ON a.id = b.tagid
WHERE   b.tagid IS NULL
```

from your query above, when using `NOT IN` (*or `IN`*), the subquery should only return one column,

```
....
WHERE ti.tagid NOT IN (SELECT tagid FROM tagitem WHERE itemid = '22')
```

Comment: I plan to put unique condition in table using phpadmin as a backup but still would like to keep tag from appearing as an option to assign if has already been assigned.  Otherwise, user may click on it and wonder what happened or notice that there is an option to do something that would be an error

Comment: I slightly simplified my question by excluding other where conditions.  User gets to search tags using ajax and they are limited by userid.  Where would I put this WHERE condition: WHERE userid = '$userid' and tag LIKE '%$str%'

Comment: why do you need `userid`? how about this query `SELECT  *
FROM tags a
  LEFT JOIN 
  (
   SELECT  tagid 
   FROM  tagitem cc
     INNER JOIN tag dd
      ON cc.tagID = dd.id
   WHERE  tag LIKE CONCAT('%', 'tagName','%')
  ) b ON a.id = b.tagid
WHERE b.tagid IS NULL`?

Comment: I am trying to make the original query work with your correction of one field.  The subquery does return the already assigned tags, however, the NOT IN does not seem to exclude them from results... userid because users create own tags.  I have always had problems with inner joins.  Is there a way to adapt your original answer to add extra where condition...or can you see why the NOT IN is not working,,,may be something needs to be in ticks or apostrophes??

Comment: so where is the `userid` column located? (*what table it belongs?*)

Comment: ok, got it to work using original query with correction to single field.  Needed tickmarks/alias in subquery.  Thx.